# Laptop Overheating with Windows 8

Tags: laptop, windows-8, overheating

I recently installed Windows 8 on my HP G62 Laptop and I have been noticing a very strange problem with it.

Let alone, for lets say 5 minutes, without even touching it, it starts to heat up and it reaches about 60 degrees (Celsius) with absolutely no applications open (not just on desktop but overall).

I dug in a little deep and found out that Maintenance was running when the computer was Idle, so I turned that off From the System's Task Scheduler, and while there I also turned off other services I did not need hoping that would solve the problem.

So after a few days, I noticed that the average temperature of my laptop dropped from 55 to 48 degrees while working on Visual Studio. And when I thought the problem had disappeared, it still did show up, only not after 5 minutes, but more like 10 minutes.

Here is what I have done so far:

- Replacing the thermal paste on the CPU and the fan and cleaning the fan (this was like 6 months ago)
- Using a laptop cooler
- Running a virus scan (I just formatted my laptop so it would be really weird if I already caught something but who knows)

Right now, I believe it has something to do with my gfx driver (Even though it IS up to date, looking closely at the screen, I can see the pixels slowly refresh (kinda like watching static on TV) which I wasn't able to do on Windows 7.

If you have any ideas, let me know.

Comment: First thing is to check if anything is using your cpu (in task manager (ctrl+shift+esc)). if everything is staying pretty low (under 5-10% when you're not doing anything) then it may not be the software/OS causing it. Also use GPUz to check GPU load and temperatures; you can then see if there is a program using your GPU a lot that is causing it to overheat.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing overheating problem, you should buy an air duster and clean cpu fans etc. with it throughly, you must do it when the PC is shutdown and also remove the batteries before using air duster.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. The processors of my of Toshiba Portegé R700 would achieve temperatures of nearly 100 degrees celsius for no reason. The fan would be blowing at full speed continuously. This started happening when I upgraded to Windows 8.

Last weekend, I made the decision to wipe the hard disk and reinstall windows 7 professional.  The machine is working like it used to: no fan noise and the CPU core temperature is only 60 degrees.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to address the problem.  Using Windows 7 isn't a real solution to the problem.  You having the same problem isn't an answer to the problem.